# Why does queue_work return 0 in linux kernel driver module

Tags: linux, module, driver

I have been porting a custom vendor class USB driver from WINCE 6.0 to Linux kernel for a custom Android device. This driver has a bulk endpoint that is used for transfer of data to a file. Please don't explain to me that is a bad idea. I understand this. In my bulkout_complete function I copy the data to a write buffer and then call queue_work to schedule a work queue to write the data to file. To ensure that the host cannot send data again until the write has completed I have a write status variable that gets cleared as the last operation in the work queue function. The host driver calls a vendor specific request on the control endpoint to monitor the status of that variable. When the variable is cleared the host will send the next packet to the bulk endpoint. The problem is that even though the variable has cleared, the next call to queue_work will return a value of zero, which seems to indicate that the work is already in progress.

From my header file:

```
u8 mWriteBuffer[4096];
u32 mWriteLength;
static bool mWriteActive = false;
#define USB_WORKQUEUE_NAME "wqusb"
static struct workqueue_struct *wqUSB;
static struct work_struct writeFile_work;
DECLARE_WORK(writeFile_work,file_write_handler);
```

Creating and cleaning up the workqueue

```
static int __init init(void)
{
    wqUSB = create_workqueue(USB_WORKQUEUE_NAME);
    // other init stuff
}
static void __exit cleanup(void)
{
    flush_workqueue(wqUSB);
    destroy_workqueue(wqUSB);
    //other cleanup stuff
}
```

Bulk endpoint code

```
static void bulkout_complete(struct usb_ep *ep, struct usb_request *req)
{
    struct usb_composite_dev    *cdev;
    struct f_myusb *ss = ep->driver_data;
    int             status = req->status;    

    cdev = ss->function.config->cdev;


    switch (status) 
    {

        case 0:             /* normal completion? */
        mWriteLength = (u32)req->length;
        memcpy(mWriteBuffer,(u8*)req->buf,req->length);
        mWriteActive = true;
        if(queue_work(wqUSB,&writeFile_work)==0)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "[USB DRIVER] - failed to queuework \n");
        }
        break;

    /* this endpoint is normally active while we're configured */
    case -ECONNABORTED:     /* hardware forced ep reset */
    case -ECONNRESET:       /* request dequeued */
    case -ESHUTDOWN:        /* disconnect from host */
        VDBG(cdev, "%s gone (%d), %d/%d\n", ep->name, status,
            req->actual, req->length);

        free_ep_req(ep, req);
        return;

    case -EOVERFLOW:        /* buffer overrun on read means that
                 * we didn't provide a big enough
                 * buffer.
                 */
    default:
    #if 1
        DBG(cdev, "%s complete --> %d, %d/%d\n", ep->name,
            status, req->actual, req->length);
    #endif
    case -EREMOTEIO:        /* short read */
        break;
    }

    status = usb_ep_queue(ep, req, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if (status) {
        ERROR(cdev, "kill %s:  resubmit %d bytes --> %d\n",
            ep->name, req->length, status);
        usb_ep_set_halt(ep);



        }
    }
```

The workqueue function that writes data

```
void file_write_handler(struct work_struct *pwork)
{
     write_file(mWriteBuffer,mWriteLength);
     mWriteActive = false;
}
```